# How to set maximum label lenght?

Tags: html, label

I've got a problem where I'm pasting information from a database from a label, but sometimes it's too big and it goes over other elements and it looks unpleasent. How can I fix this?

```
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-pireus" id="lvOccupationL2">Професия Ниво 3:</span>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Occupation" CssClass="form-control form-control-readonly"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `text-overflow` option to assign on your label element. It has several interesting options; read more about it here:

- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow